# How can I install and use Jupyter scratchpad extenstion in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am wondering if there is a way to install and use the jupyter scratchpad extension in vscode. Or if there is any good scratchpad extension alternative in vscode.

Comment: I already have jupyter notebook installed on vscode. I am asking about the Jupyter SCRATCHPAD extension which is an extension in jupyter notebook